# What does the new keyword do under the hood?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, object, new-operator

I am curious as what else the `new` keyword does in the background apart from changing what the `this` scope refers too.

For example if we compare using the `new` keyword to make a function set properties and methods on an object to just making a function return a new object, is there anything extra that the new object does?

And which is preferred if I don't wish to create multiple objects from the function constructor

```
var foo2 = function () {
  var temp = "test";

  return {
    getLol: function () {
      return temp;
    },

    setLol: function(value) {
      temp = value;
    }
  };

}();

var foo = new function () {
  var temp = "test";

  this.getLol = function () {
    return temp;
  }

  this.setLol = function(value) {
    temp = value;
  }
}();
```

The firebug profiler tells me using the new keyword is slightly faster (2ms instead of 3ms), on large objects is new still significantly faster?

[Edit]

Another matter is on really large object constructors is having a return at the bottom of the function (It will have a large amount of local functions) or having a few this.bar = ... at the top of the function more readable? What is considered a good convention?

```
var MAIN = newfunction() {
    this.bar = ...

    // Lots of code
}();

var MAIN2  = function() {
    // Lots of code

    return {
        bar: ...
    }
}();
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [Is it right to think of a Javascript Function Expression that uses the 'new' keyword as 'static'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572) - except for the question in the title

Comment: For the title question, see [JavaScript: How does 'new' work internally](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6750880/1048572)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting [Douglas Crockford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) from [the Good Parts book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) (page 47), to answer the title of this question:

> If the `new` operator were a method instead of an operator, it could be implemented like this:

```
Function.method('new', function () {

   // Create a new object that inherits from the 
   // constructor's prototype.

   var that = Object.create(this.prototype);

   // Invoke the constructor, binding -this- to
   // the new object.

   var other = this.apply(that, arguments);

   // If its return value isn't an object,
   // substitute the new object.

   return (typeof other === 'object' && other) || that;
});
```

The `Function.method` method is implemented as follows. This adds an instance method to a class ([Source](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html#sugar)):

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
   this.prototype[name] = func;
   return this;
};
```

Further reading:

- [Mozilla Dev Center: `Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
- [Mozilla Dev Center: `Function.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- [Douglas Crockford: Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html)

Comment: Now I only have to figure out what this.prototype, this.apply & Function.method do internally :). Sometimes I feel I should just assume and hack around more and try to understand internals less.

Comment: @Raynos: `Function.method` is not a built-in method. Added some further info on this.

Comment: Thank you, I will take some time to read those in the future. Still getting the hang of prototyping.

Comment: Seems that Mr. Crockford forgot that functions are also objects hehe (it will still return `that` if `other` is a function)

Comment: @CMS: The constructor will only return a function when constructing a function with `new Function()`, right? In that case the above would not work, unless we check for `typeof other === 'function'` as well. Is that right, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Daniel, the [`[[Construct]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2.2) internal operation checks if the result of invoking the constructor function is *not* a primitive, if that's the case (an object was returned) that value is used as the result of the `NewExpression`. If you have a constructor that returns a function and you use the `new` operator on it, that function will be the result of the `NewExpression`, because the return value is not a primitive, is a function object. I would check something like [this](http://gist.github.com/528942) (see line *15*).

Comment: ...  I think [this](http://jsbin.com/ipipa3/edit) example can express exactly what I mean ;)

Comment: @CMS: Ok got it now... It's that the return value of the constructor can be explicitly overridden with the return statement, as in your jsbin example, returning a function... Thanks for the detailed explanation... I'll update my answer in a minute to reflect your comments :)

Answer (score 6):

Read [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). Sections [11.2.2](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.2) and [13.2.2](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2.2) are relevant and aren't too tricky to understand (note that the latter two links are to non-official HTML-ified version of the spec).

In summary, if you have a function `f` that returns an object, the only observable difference that calling it with `new` will make is that the `this` value will be different, and that calling it with `new` *may* be slower, since it involves additional steps of creating an object and assigning it a few properties.

Comment: Sounds like `new` is an anti-pattern then?  I was wondering why objects needed `new` at all.  To make it look more like Java/C++?

Comment: @thomson-comer It's not an anti-pattern, it gives the object its own `this` variable