# How does the new operator work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, new-operator

Probably the least understood part of JavaScript, standing beside the prototype chain.

So the question is: how does...

```
new dataObj(args);
```

...actually create an object, and define its prototype chain/constructors/etc?

Best is to show an alternative, to fully understand this keyword.

Comment: Sort of related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `new` operator uses the internal [`[[Construct]]`](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.2) method, and it basically does the following:

- Initializes a new native object
- Sets the internal `[[Prototype]]` of this object, pointing to the Function `prototype` property.

  - If the function's `prototype` property is not an object (a primitive values, such as a Number, String, Boolean, Undefined or Null), `Object.prototype` is used instead.
- After creating the object, it calls the function, providing the object as its `this` value.
- If the return value of the called function, is a primitive, the object created internally is returned.
- Otherwise, if an object is returned, the object created internally is lost.

An equivalent implementation of what the `new` operator does, can be expressed like this (assuming that the ECMAScript 5 `Object.create` method is available):

```
function NEW(f) {
  var obj, ret, proto;

  // Check if `f.prototype` is an object, not a primitive
  proto = Object(f.prototype) === f.prototype ? f.prototype : Object.prototype;

  // Create an object that inherits from `proto`
  obj = Object.create(proto);

  // Apply the function setting `obj` as the `this` value
  ret = f.apply(obj, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

  if (Object(ret) === ret) { // the result is an object?
    return ret;
  }
  return obj;
}

// Example usage:
function Foo (arg) {
  this.prop = arg;
}
Foo.prototype.inherited = 'baz';

var obj = NEW(Foo, 'bar');
obj.prop;          // 'bar'
obj.inherited;     // 'baz'
obj instanceof Foo // true
```

Comment: Would it be safe to replace Object.create(proto) with > var newObj = {}; newObj.prototype = proto; ?

Comment: @pico.creator: No, the `prototype` property is only meaningful for Function objects, when used as constructors, and using a constructor in my example implementation of `new`, would have needed to use the `new` operator anyway... The only other way around would be to use the `__proto__` property, but it's non-standard and it is being deprecated. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111288/#2111353) in which I explain the difference between the `prototype` property of function objects and the *internal* `[[Prototype]]` property that all objects have forming the prototype chain.

Comment: The dual usage of the term is certainly confusing. However the answer left out the setting of object constructor; Cause from my experiments, seems like the constructor function is cloned, applied, and added to the result .constructor value.

Comment: I'm assuming the `arguments` in the example are supposed to be `f`.. or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

The expression `new C(arg1, arg2)`:

Assuming C is a JavaScript function (otherwise you get an error):

1. Creates a new empty object (no properties)
2. Sets the prototype of the new object to the value of the
   "`prototype`" property of `C`.

   - Note: The default value of `prototype` for a function is an object (automatically created when the function is declared) with its prototype set to `Object.prototype` and a `constructor` property pointing back to the function `C`.
   - Note: The terminology can be confusing. The property named "prototype" is *not* the same as the prototype of the object. Only functions have the property named "prototype", but all objects have a prototype.
3. Calls the function `C` with '`this`' set to the new object, and with the supplied arguments.
4. If calling the function `C` returns an object, this object is the result of the expression. Otherwise the newly created object is the result of the expression.

An alternative to `new` in ECMAScript 5 would be to use the builtin `Object.createObject` method.

`new C(arg1, arg2)` would be equivalent to:

```
var obj = Object.createObject(C.prototype);
C.apply(obj, [arg1, arg2]);
```

Standard JavaScript does not allow you to explicitly set the prototype of an object, so `Object.createObject` cannot be implemented in the language itself. Some implementations does allow it through the non-standard property __proto__. In that case, `new C` can be simulated like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.__proto__ = C.prototype;
C.apply(obj, [arg1, arg2]);
```

Comment: Note on the point #2: The default value of the `prototype` property of any user defined function, is an object that contains the `constructor` property that refers back to the function itself, and it inherits from `Object.prototype`. This object is initialized when [function objects are created](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2). About `Object.create`, it can be just be *partially* emulated on ES3, setting the `[[Prototype]]` property can be done through a temporary constructor, but yes, it's impossible to emulate completely, [see more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830800#3844768). Cheers.