# how does new Number(value) work in js?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var num = new Number(43);
console.log(num);
</script>
```

According to the tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp

```
Syntax
var num = new Number(value);
Note: If the value parameter cannot be converted into a number, it returns NaN (Not-a-Number).
```

Question:

In firebug->console, it shows: `Number {}` , not what I expect `Number {43}`, no matter what number i put in `new Number(value)`; it always shows:`Number {}` so what is the purpose to use `new Number(value)`? how does it work? BTW, I googled on line, but did not find a good explanation.

Comment: [obligatory w3fools reference](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/ lol @zzzzBov looks like you won the "race".

Comment: Its just an object wrapper for a number, if you want to know the value of the wrapped number just call `valuOf`.

Comment: Here is some good documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between a number primitive and a number object. When you use the `new` keyword, you create a new number object, which is what you see. You can get the value of the number object with `valueOf`, which returns the primitive:

```
> var n = new Number(42);
> n.valueOf()
42
```

Comment: so is '42'stored as a property in number object?

Comment: @user2294256: Not as a property like `n.something = 12` is, but yes, sort of.

Comment: after this line runs: var n = new Number(42);is there a way that I can see what is the content inside object Number? I want to see how '42' stored in object Number?

Comment: @user2294256: You can't. `Number` is implemented in native code.

Answer (score 1):

`Number(43)` is a number primitive but `new Number(43)` will create an object from that number primitive. The display `Number {}` is just how the Chrome console displays an object like that.

`new Number(43)` will still "behave" like a number. In the console:

```
var num = new Number(43); // Number {}
num == 43 // true
num + 5 // 48
num === 43 // false, since the types don't match.
```

For more info on how `new` works: [How does the new operator work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750880/javascript-how-does-new-work-internally). If you just want a number primitive, don't use `new`.