# How does the "new" keyword work as described in ECMAScript 5 standard

Tags: javascript

I want to know how the `new` operator work and not just learn how to use it.I looked in the [ECMAScript 5 standard](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.2) and find the algorithm describe how it work but am a little confused about the meanning of it.

> The production `NewExpression : new NewExpression`is evaluated as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Let `ref` be the result of evaluating NewExpression.
> 2. Let `constructor` be GetValue(ref).
> 3. If `Type(constructor)` is not `Object`, throw a `TypeError` exception.
> 4. If `constructor` does not implement the `[[Construct]]` internal method, throw a `TypeError` exception.
> 5. Return the result of calling the `[[Construct]]` internal method on `constructor`, providing no arguments (that  is, an empty list of arguments).

I try to understand the algorithm above using this example:

```
var f = function() {};    
var h = new f();
```

Particularly I don't understand the first step and therefore cannot follow the other steps.

> 1. Let `ref` be the result of evaluating NewExpression.

```
var h = new f();
        ~~~ ~~~~
         |    \_________ NewExpression 
     new operator
```

Does that mean `ref` is the value of `f()`? But It's `undefined`.

> 3 . If `Type(constructor)` is not `Object`, throw a `TypeError` exception.

But the type of `f` is function, will it throw a `TypeError` exception?

> 5 . Return the result of calling the `[[Construct]]` internal method on `constructor`, providing no arguments (that  is, an empty list of arguments).

`[[Construct]]` internal property of function, What's the meaning of calling it on `constructor`?

Comment: Please note that `new f;` is `new NewExpression` while `new f();` is `new MemberExpression Arguments`, with an empty `Arguments`.

Comment: See also [How does `new` work internally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750880/javascript-how-does-new-work-internally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we have to clarify what `new NewExpression` and especially `NewExpression` are. This can be found in [Annex A](http://es5.github.io/#A.3). The most common situation where this rule applies is when you don't pass arguments to the constructor. I.e.

```
var obj = new F;
```

where `F` refers to a function. So this is the rule that lets you omit the parenthesis.

In your example (`var h = new f();`), you have parenthesis though, i.e. you are passing an empty list of arguments, so this algorithm **does not apply**. `f()` is *not* `NewExpression`.

Instead this algorithm applies: `new MemberExpression Arguments`. It is evaluated in pretty much the same way and the algorithm can found in [§11.2.2](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.2) as well, just after the algorithm you quoted.

With this in mind, lets go through that algorithm step by step:

> 1. Let `ref` be the result of evaluating `MemberExpression`.

In your example, `MemberExpression`, is `f`, i.e. it is a variable. [The result of the evaluation](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.2) is a special [*Reference*](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7) object. It's not important here *what* exactly it is. Just know that it holds information about how to actually get the value from the variable.
So now `ref` refers to that reference.

> 2. Let `constructor` be `GetValue(ref)`.

This is were the value of the variable is actually retrieved and `constructor` will refer to the function that `f` refers to.

> 3. Let `argList` be the result of evaluating `Arguments`, producing an internal list of argument values ([11.2.4](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.4)).

In your case, `Arguments` is `()` and therefore it is an empty list.

> 4. If `Type(constructor)` is not `Object`, throw a `TypeError` exception.

It is important to know that **functions are objects** too! So this step will throw the error if *primitive values* are being used in the `new` expression.

> 5. If `constructor` does not implement the `[[Construct]]` internal method, throw a `TypeError` exception.

All functions (and potentially other objects) implement an internal `[[Construct]]` property which does the actual instantiation of the new object. If the object does not have such a property, it cannot be used as constructor. How it works for functions is defined in [§13.2.2](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2).

> 6. Return the result of calling the `[[Construct]]` internal method on constructor, providing the list `argList` as the argument values.

This is were the actual construction happens. `[[Construct]]` is itself function and is defined in [§13.2.2](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2). The method is the same of every function and is responsible for creating a new object, call the function on that new object and return it or whatever the function returns.

Here is an example of what it would look in JavaScript (partly pseudo-code):

```
[[Construct]] = function(F, argList) {
    // Create new object that in inherits from F.prototype or Object.prototype
    var proto = F.prototype;
    var obj = Object.create(typeof proto === 'object' ? proto : Object.prototype);

    // Call F with this set to obj and pass the argument list
    var result = F.apply(obj, argList);

    // If result is not an object, return the generated object
    return typeof result === 'object' ? result : obj;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through this step by step

1. Resolve things like `new window['foo' + 1 + 'bar']` -> `new window.foo1bar`
2. determine what object is actually referenced: What is `window`? Local variable or property of the global object?
3. This is obvious.
4. Not so obvious, but the point is: every `Function` is a constructor, but not every constructor is a `Function`. This point makes sure that `new` is only called on constructors.
5. Run the constructor. Note that the spec also provides `MemberExpression : new MemberExpression Arguments` for the case `new foo(...)`