# Understanding JavaScript class methods and prototype

Tags: javascript

First example:

```
function Animal(name) {
    // Instance properties can be set on each instance of the class
    this.name = name;
    this.speak = function() {
        console.log("My name is " + this.name);
    }
}

var animal = new Animal('Petname1');
animal.speak();


function Cat(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name);
}

Cat.prototype = new Animal();

var cat = new Cat('Petname2');
console.log(cat.speak());
```

Second example:

```
function Animal(name) {
    // Instance properties can be set on each instance of the class
    this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function() {
    console.log("My name is " + this.name);
};

var animal = new Animal('Petname1');
animal.speak();


function Cat(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name);
}

Cat.prototype = new Animal();

var cat = new Cat('Petname2');
console.log(cat.speak());
```

In the first example I'm adding directly to class, in the second example I'm adding through `prototype`. What is the difference? Output is the same.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: I don't see the `'Monty'` String anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to understand how the `new` works on Javascript and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750880/javascript-how-does-new-work-internally) has a good explanation about it.

Based on that, the difference between your two approaches is the quantity of `speak` functions that is being created while creating new Animals and Cats.

The first approach will have the same instance number of `speak` function than of `Cat` and `Animal`. However the second approach will have only one `speak` function, no matter how many Cats and Animals you have instantiated. Check out the following snippets.

At this one we can see that 'speak' functions are different for the two Animal instances.

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.speak = function() {
        console.log("My name is " + this.name);
    }
}

var animalA = new Animal();
var animalB = new Animal();

animalA.speak === animalB.speak // false
```

Assigning to prototype we can see that it is the same for two instances.

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function() {
    console.log("My name is " + this.name);
};

var animalA = new Animal();
var animalB = new Animal();

animalA.speak === animalB.speak // true
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example `speak()` is attached to each Animal object created. you can change the behavior of `speak()` for an object during runtime, it will only be done for that particular object.

However, second example has `speak()` is defined once and all objects will get updated version if at all it is changed through `Animal.prototype.speak` assignment.