# In javascript, does the new operator always return an object of same type which is mentioned in the new statement?

Tags: javascript, new-operator, instanceof

Given this code:

```
function foo(){ 
   return foo; 
}
var bar = new foo();

console.log(bar instanceof foo);
```

I expect the output to be "true". However, it is "false".

Why is the bar object not of type foo?

On the other hand if I just return a number (say 2) from foo, I get the output as true.

Comment: Almost a duplicate? [JavaScript: How does 'new' work internally](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6750880/218196)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you return a primitive (say 2) from a constructor, the return value is ignored. The object created by [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) is returned instead, just like when a constructor has no return statement. If you return an object from a constructor, the object is returned (note: functions are objects in Javascript), whether or not that object has the constructor as its internal prototype.

In your case you are returning a function; that function is foo, but it is not an instance of foo.

[See **new operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: if you `return this;` in `foo()` it becomes true

Comment: I'd appreciate it if someone could edit the link in. I clearly forget how to do it manually and I'm on mobile ;)