# How come instance is not undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var instance;
function Universe() {
    return instance;
};
instance = new Universe();
```

How come that instance is not undefined?

Comment: What is the purpose of the code you've written?

Comment: The question is _What does `new` return?_ Answer: `object`

Comment: @Andy I'd say the only purpose is to test the SO community and other JavaScript programmers.

Comment: "How come that instance is not undefined?" Because it is defined?

Comment: If a `return` statement is executed in a function invoked with `new`, and the returned value is not an object reference, the returned value is ignored and the object instantiated as a side-effect of `new` is returned instead.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2

Comment: Javascript functions are objects. Even if you change your function to not return anything, the result will still be the same.

Comment: I create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dckch1br/) to test it, the `instance` isn't undefined.

Comment: See also [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1048572)/[How does the `new` operator/keyword work internally](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6750880/1048572)

Comment: if you just called Universe() as a function, then it would return instance, but you're calling Universe() via new, so it's going to return a fresh object based on the prototype template defined by your Universe() function.

Comment: @Pointy, in this case after the first call all other calls will return same instance of object, stored in `instance` variable.

Comment: @VasylMoskalov yes, that is exactly correct.

Comment: @ManoDestra. Nope! Only first call (or any other call to Universe in case of `instance` is not instance of Universe) return fresh object. In case of `instance` is instance of Universe any call to new Universe() will return same object, stored in instance variable.

Comment: this is an implementation of a singleton pattern. thanks everyone for help

Comment: @VasylMoskalov That is precisely what I stated above. It returns a new object **"based on the prototype template defined by your Universe() function"**. If instance has changed, since the first call, then clearly that would affect what the Universe() function then defines for the new object.