# Javascript Help: Functions/Objects

Tags: javascript, function, object, javascript-objects

So, using Code Academy I'm in the Objects section of the Javascript tutorial and I'm having a really hard time wrapping my brain around Functions & Objects. I'd like some help and explaining with parts of the code below. I've commented on each line what I need help with. Thanks so much in advance.

```
// Obviously declaring the Rabbit function with adjective to be called

function Rabbit(adjective) { 

  // I don't understand this line, or the context of why this is being used.

  this.adjective = adjective; 

  // Why declare another function here? Is a function within a function 
  // considered a Method or is that only Function within an Object?

  this.describeMyself = function() { 

    // I get this part but why does it need a function to do this?

    console.log("I am a " + this.adjective + " rabbit"); 
  };
}

// I don't get this either, Isn't this declaring a new object? How can   
// that be when you only have a Function named Rabbit?

var rabbit1 = new Rabbit("fluffy"); 
var rabbit2 = new Rabbit("happy");
var rabbit3 = new Rabbit("sleepy");

// How could this work if describeMyself is in the Rabbit function and 
// has nothing to do with rabit1?

console.log(rabbit1.describeMyself); 
console.log(rabbit2.describeMyself);
console.log(rabbit3.describeMyself);
```

Hopefully not too confusing but if any of you more experienced Javascript people could kindly explain out everything I talked about in the comments I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: A "method" in programming languages generally is a function attached as a property or child of an object (but the EMCAScript specification that defines JavaScript never uses the word "method" to describe any feature of the language; it's just a general word). For the rest, this is generally answered by [JavaScript: How does 'new' work internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750880/javascript-how-does-new-work-internally) although the answers there may assume a strong command of the language already. The short answer is `new` invokes a function with a newly-created `this` object.

Comment: Note that your course is teaching a technique that still works but which has been generally [considered superseded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) by the most recent version of Javascript.  But if you have experience with any modern OOP language (C++, Ruby, Java), it should be easy enough to find parallels with their notions of classes, methods, etc.  But be warned that the underlying mechanism (prototypal delegation) is significantly different.

Comment: To correct my earlier comment: the spec actually *does* explicitly define "method" as "function that is the value of a property". (I mistakenly thought it did not provide such a definition for that category of function.)

Answer (score 1):

1. `Rabbit` is a **constructor**, which produces an **instance** when called with `new` keyword.
2. When you do that, **`this` points to the instance you created**.

So, by `var rabbit1 = new Rabbit('fluffy')`, you created an object looks somehow like this and assign to variable `rabbit1`:

```
{
  adjective: 'fluffy',
  describeMyself: function() {...}
}
```

As `this` in `rabbit1.describeMyself` points to the instance itself (`rabbit1`), when you call `rabbit1.describeMyself()`, `this.adjective` actually gives you `rabbit1.adjective`. That's why you get `'fluffy'`.

For `rabbit2` and `rabbit3`, `this` points to themselves respectively.

Comment: I'd suggest you read an entry level book. Cross-coupled topics are very common in learning a programming language, online series usually cannot handle such situations well.

Comment: Moreover, **any** function can be used as a constructor, simply by `var something = new myFunction()`.  By convention, constructor functions are capitalized to distinguish them.

Comment: @ScottSauyet `new` any function wouldn't be quite meaningful, if it's not composed in purpose of a constructor. But yes, you could `new` it anyway :)

Comment: In fact, it could be actively harmful, if it did something to `this` that was really meant to be used in a different manner.  But it's been done.  I know, I've seen it... I've cleaned up the resulting mess.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the critical thing that helped me understand JavaScript, was the realization that JavaScript functions ***are*** objects.

A JavaScript object can contain a function as one of the values of an array or as the value of a deeper object.

So, in your question about `this.adjective`, you are storing the passed in (from the outside) `adjective` inside the scope of `function Rabbit` which becomes Rabbit.adjective to the larger outside scope.  If you didn't set it to a property of `Rabbit` then Rabbit.adjective would be `undefined` in the larger outside scope closure, but would be available to anything inside of `Rabbit`.

> console.log(rabbit1.describeMyself); // How could this work if
>   describeMyself is in the Rabbit function and has nothing to do with
>   rabit1?

In this case `rabbit1` has inherited the properties of `Rabbit` by being first instantiated (created) from a prototype (sort of like a parent that you can always copy from but can't copy back to--so by value) so that it has all the same properties as `Rabbit` but with the different data inject from the `new` line.  In this way you can use what's in `Rabbit` inside `rabbit1` without contaminating `Rabbit` and being able to customize `Rabbit` by having as many instances of `Rabbit` (Rabbit1, Rabbit2, etc) as you want.

If you ask why you might want to do this the answer lies in code modularity and reusability.  As project code bases get bigger and more complex with more developers working on them, you'll want to create standards that can be followed and reused by everyone working on the project.

Comment: I believe I understand well what happens in the code, but this explanation baffles me.  For starters, the fact that functions happen to actually be objects is irrelevant to all of this.  If they shared no hierarchy, everything would work the same.  And while, yes, there are prototypes to be considered (missing from Leo's answer above), this doesn't serve to explain them, and I think the OP should probably walk before running.