# how does "new" work with classes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How does the `new` work differently in the 2 examples below? I see that the 2nd example is replacing the annoymous funciton with a variable, but in the second one, the function/class "Person" is actually being called. Does it make any difference if it's being called or not? I tried it without the calling and it still worked. So that led me to believe that new is actually calling the function and setting up `this` to be assigned to the instance variable.

```js
 var person = new function() {  
        this.setName = function(name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        this.sayHi = function() {
            return "Hi, my name is " + this.name;
        }
    }
    person.setName("Rafael");  
    console.log(person.sayHi()); // Hi, my name is Rafael
```

```js
    var Person = function() {
        this.setName = function(name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        this.sayHi = function() {
            return "Hi, my name is " + this.name;
        }
    }
    
    var personTwo = new Person()
    
    personTwo.setName("Rafael");
    console.log(personTwo.sayHi()); // Hi, my name is Rafael
```

Comment: There are no classes in javascript (though there is a *class* syntax). How do you intend to create a second instance in the first example?

Comment: Sort of related to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750880/how-does-the-new-operator-work-in-javascript , and, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be almost no difference between these two examples, if it was a simple function like this:

```js
(function() { console.log("IIFE"); })();

// or

var f = function() { console.log("Function"); };
f();
```

You just store your function in a variable, and then call it.

However, it makes a little difference, since it is related to JS OOP mechanisms. In the first case you get `Object` instance, and in the second you get `Person` instance. This makes difference in OOP sense.

```js
var person = new function() { };
console.log("Is instance of: " + person.constructor.name);
console.log("There is no way to check instanceof in this case");

var Person = function() { };
var person = new Person();
console.log("Is instance of: " + person.constructor.name);
console.log(person instanceof Person);
```

In general, `new` and classes are supposed to be used as in the second case in order to enable the full functionality of JS OOP. There is absolutely no sense or/and advantage in using anonymous class constructor.

Comment: Note that the constructor property and *instanceof* are unreliable ways of determining whether an object is an instance of a particular "class".  E.g. `var Fred = Person; var fred = new Fred; fred.constructor.name // Person`.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it is assigned into a variable: does not matter. It is completely parallel to this example:

```
var x = 1;
console.log(x);
```

and

```
console.log(1);
```

Whether it needs to be called or not: A function with the `new` operator is always being called, but with `new`, parentheses are optional when no parameters are passed: `new Person()` is equivalent to `new Person`, but `new Person("Joe")` cannot be done differently.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, you are passing to the *new* operator the exact same function. You simply are using a reference (logically stored in a variable) instead of writing literal function just in place.

So, your second example is **the same** as:

```
var personTwo = new (function() {  
    [...]
})()
[...]
```

Which, in fact, is much the same as the first one:

```
var person = new (function() {  
    [...]
})
[...]
```

> **NOTE** that the parentheses surrounding the function are absolutely optional in this case. You could be placed there seven if you like: `(((((((function(){[...]})))))))`.

The point here is that when you say *«in the second one, the function/class "Person" is actually being called»* **you are WRONG there:** That function, which acts as a *constructor* isn't being called **by you**. You are simply passing it as a parameter (the constructor function) of the *new* operator which is, in fact, who is actually calling the constructor with the rest of parameters you provided, if any.

See [*new* syntax documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

```
new constructor[([arguments])]
```

The *constructor* is the function you pass to the new operator and the parameters are specified between parentheses. But they are fully optional (including the parentheses itself).

This is why `new constructor;` without parentheses works.

To be clear: What you thought happens (but not) would be written as:

```
var person = new ((function(){...})()) ();
```

...or, more verbosely:

```
    var person = new (
        (function(){ // Constructor builder.
            [...]
            return function(){...}; // Actual constructor.
        })() // Constructor builder call
  //v-- Parentheses to force builder to be called.
    ) (); // <-- Parameters (if any) passed to the constructor.
```