# Why the last step return Javascript even the object has no such key value pair?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototype

I can understand another_stooge.name return javascript because of the prototype and also understand the return new f() create a brand new object and didn't understand how prototype share details just by inside the  "f.prototype = stooge" function.?

```js
if (typeof Object.beget !== 'funcion') {
  Object.beget = function() {
    var f = function() {};
    f.prototype = stooge;
    return new f();
  }
}
var stooge = {}; // empty object;
var new_stooge = {}; // empty object;
new_stooge.title = "My first title";
new_stooge.color = "white";
var another_stooge = Object.beget(stooge);
stooge.name = 'Javscript';
console.log(another_stooge.name); // Return Javscript ?.
```

Comment: cause Object.beget doesnt make sense? use Object.create

Comment: You put the `stooge` object in the prototype chain, so looking up the "name" property checks the object and then checks its constructor's protoype.

Comment: `funcion` is misspelled too

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [How does the new operator work in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750880/how-does-the-new-operator-work-in-javascript) Calling `new f()` creates a new object whose prototype is `f.prototype`. Therefore, setting `f.prototype` to `stooge` causes `new f()` to create an object whose prototype is `stooge`.

Comment: Thanks for the help this is just for learning javascript objects and its prototype....