# Keyword new on static method Promise.resolve

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I saw this 'erroneous' calling of `new` keyword on `Promise.resolve`, but I am surprised that it works! Can someone please explain to me what is happening, and if it is different in any way to omitting the `new` keyword?

```
new Promise.resolve(1)
```

Looking at the MDN documentations for [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Associativity) (specifically *Member Access*, *Function Call* and *new(without argument list)*) and [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), shouldn't the above throw error, since I assume the expression is getting evaluated like such:

```
new (Promise.resolve(1))
```

I think I am missing something (obvious) here. Thanks in advance!

Note: Using bluebird library 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750880/how-does-the-new-operator-work-in-javascript/6751026#6751026) is a very good answer describing how the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator works in JavaScript.

Essentially what is happening is that `Promise.resolve` is being treated as a constructor, however the constructed object is being discarded since `Promise.resolve` returns something (your promise object).

In this case, the `new` does no harm since `Promise.resolve` doesn't depend on access to `this` and, if you wish, it can simply be removed.

Conversely, adding `new` to an instance method invocation will result in very weird behaviour:

```js
let x = Promise.resolve()
new x.then(() => console.log("Resolved")) // Will almost certainly throw an error
```

Comment: "Essentially what is happening is that Promise.resolve is being treated as a constructor" Do you mean that the expression above is being evaluated like such: `new (Promise.resolve)(1)`?

Comment: In JavaScript everything is, at its core, an object - so `new` doesn't know the difference between `new Promise()` and `new X()` (where `X = Promise.resolve`). So yes, while your brackets make the code look very odd, the evaluation order that they imply is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is really just creating a new object and calls the given function with `this` set to that object. If `Promise.resolve` internally doesn't use `this` at all, then that makes no difference. Further, if the given constructor function returns an object itself, then the implicit object created by `new` gets discarded and the returned object is used instead.

So, `new` introduces a new intermediate object which gets discarded here since `resolve` returns a `Promise`, and it sets the context to a different object which doesn't seem to have any influence.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any influence _except for extraneous memory consumption and decrease in performance due to unnecessary overhead, of course_.

Comment: I mean *in functionality*.

Comment: It wasn't a criticism of your answer, more of an assurance to OP that "erroneous" shouldn't be in quotes, and that "it works" isn't a justification for accepting this practice.