# D3 custom curve: bundle interpolation for areas

Tags: javascript, d3.js, interpolation, curve

Consider this D3JS graph which uses a *basis* interpolation:

[image: D3JS v3, basis interpolation]

In D3JS v3, I could use *bundle* interpolation (`.interpolate("bundle").tension(0)`) on areas to achieve this type of rendering instead:

[image: D3JS v3, bundle interpolation]

Notice how each segment of the graph fits nicely with its neighbors. This is what I need.

With D3JS v4 and v5, the syntax for bundle interpolation is now this: `.curve(d3.curveBundle)`. However, it's now ["intended to work with d3.line, not d3.area."](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#curveBundle)

I recently upgraded from v3 to v5, and so I'm **trying to create a custom bundle curve that will work with areas too**, to keep the interpolation type I enjoyed with v3.

I'm very close. This is what I have so far:

```js
///////////////////// Custom curves.

/** Bundle-ish.
 * Trying to adapt curveBundle for use with areas…
 */
function myBundle(context, beta) {
 this._basis = new d3.curveBasis(context);
 this._beta = beta;

 this._context = context; // temporary. shouldn't be needed for bundle.
}
myBundle.prototype = {

 areaStart: function() {
  this._line = 0;
 },
 areaEnd: function() {
  this._line = NaN;
 },
 lineStart: function() {
  this._x = [];
  this._y = [];
  this._basis.lineStart();
 },
 lineEnd: function() {
  var x = this._x,
    y = this._y,
    j = x.length - 1;

  if (j > 0) {
   var x0 = x[0],
     y0 = y[0],
     dx = x[j] - x0,
     dy = y[j] - y0,
     i = -1,
     t;

   while (++i <= j) {
    t = i / j;
    this._basis.point(
     this._beta * x[i] + (1 - this._beta) * (x0 + t * dx),
     this._beta * y[i] + (1 - this._beta) * (y0 + t * dy)
    );
   }
  }

  this._x = this._y = null;
  this._basis.lineEnd();
 },
 point: function(x, y) {
  this._x.push(+x);
  this._y.push(+y);
  // console.log( this._x.push(+x), this._y.push(+y) );
 }
};
myCurveBundle = (function custom(beta) {
 function myCurveBundle(context) {
  return beta === 1 ? new myBasis(context) : new myBundle(context, beta);
 }

 myCurveBundle.beta = function(beta) {
  return custom(+beta);
 };

 return myCurveBundle;
})(0.85);






///////////////////// The chart.

 var width = 960;
 var height = 540;
 var data = [];
 data.prosody = [116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.578, 125.552, 134.888, 144.225, 153.561, 162.898, 172.235, 181.571, 190.908, 200.244, 209.581, 218.917, 227.715, 218.849, 209.591, 200.333, 191.076, 181.818, 172.560, 163.302, 154.044, 144.787, 135.529, 126.271, 117.013, 107.755, 98.498, 89.240, 97.511, 118.857, 140.202, 161.547, 182.893, 192.100, 188.997, 185.895, 182.792, 179.690, 176.587, 173.485, 170.382, 167.280, 164.177, 161.075, 157.972, 154.870, 151.767, 148.665, 145.562, 142.460, 139.357, 136.255, 133.152, 130.050, 126.947, 124.244, 122.275, 120.307, 118.338, 116.369, 114.400, 112.431, 110.462, 108.493, 106.524, 104.555, 102.586, 100.617, 98.648, 99.659, 101.531, 103.402, 105.273, 107.145, 109.016, 110.887, 112.758, 114.630, 116.501, 118.372, 120.244, 122.115, 123.986, 125.857, 127.729, 129.600, 131.471, 133.343, 135.214, 137.085, 138.956, 140.828, 142.699, 144.570, 146.442, 148.313, 150.184, 149.175, 146.384, 143.594, 140.803, 138.013, 135.222, 132.432, 129.642, 126.851, 124.061, 121.270, 118.480, 115.689, 112.899, 110.109, 107.318, 104.528, 101.737, 98.947, 96.156, 93.366, 90.576, 87.785, 84.995, 82.204, 79.414, 76.623, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 76.601, 78.414, 80.227, 82.041, 83.854, 85.667, 87.480, 89.294, 91.107, 92.920, 94.733, 96.547, 98.360, 100.173, 101.986, 103.800, 105.613, 107.426, 109.239, 111.053, 112.866, 114.679, 116.492, 115.917, 114.338, 112.760, 111.181, 109.602, 108.023, 106.444, 104.865, 103.286, 101.707, 100.128, 98.549, 96.970, 95.391, 93.812, 92.233, 90.654, 89.075, 87.534, 88.055, 88.646, 89.237, 89.827, 90.418, 91.009, 91.600, 92.191, 92.782, 93.373, 93.964, 94.555, 95.146, 95.737, 96.328, 96.919, 97.509, 98.100, 98.691, 99.282, 99.873, 100.062, 98.230, 96.399, 94.567, 92.736, 90.904, 89.072, 87.241, 85.409, 83.578, 81.746, 79.914, 78.083, 78.839, 80.880, 82.922, 84.964, 87.006, 89.048, 91.090, 93.132, 95.174, 97.216, 99.257, 101.299, 103.341, 105.383, 107.425, 109.467, 111.509, 113.551, 112.633, 110.755, 108.877, 106.999, 105.121, 103.243, 101.365, 99.487, 97.609, 95.731, 93.853, 91.975, 90.097, 88.219, 86.341, 84.463, 82.585, 80.707, 78.829, 76.951, 78.067, 81.290, 84.513, 87.736, 90.958, 94.181, 97.404, 100.627, 103.849, 107.072, 110.295, 113.517, 116.740, 119.963, 123.186, 126.408, 129.631, 132.854, 136.077, 139.299, 142.522, 145.745, 148.968, 152.190, 155.413, 154.840, 152.899, 150.958, 149.017, 147.076, 145.135, 143.194, 141.253, 139.312, 137.371, 135.429, 133.488, 131.547, 129.606, 127.665, 125.724, 124.874, 126.734, 128.594, 130.454, 132.314, 134.174, 136.034, 137.894, 139.754, 141.614, 143.474, 145.334, 147.194, 149.054, 150.914, 152.774, 154.634, 156.494, 158.354, 160.214, 162.074, 163.934, 165.664, 161.795, 157.761, 153.726, 149.692, 145.658, 141.624, 137.589, 133.555, 129.521, 125.487, 121.452, 117.418, 113.384, 109.350, 105.316, 101.281, 97.247, 93.213, 89.179, 85.144, 81.110, 77.076, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];
 data.TextGrid = {  "phone" : [ /** segment type, beginning, and end of each segment **/ [ "sp", 0.0124716553288, 0.271882086168 ], [ "M", 0.271882086168, 0.401587301587 ], [ "OW", 0.401587301587, 0.521315192744 ], [ "S", 0.521315192744, 0.660997732426 ], [ "T", 0.660997732426, 0.710884353741 ], [ "AH", 0.710884353741, 0.760770975057 ], [ "V", 0.760770975057, 0.820634920635 ], [ "DH", 0.820634920635, 0.860544217687 ], [ "IY", 0.860544217687, 0.940362811791 ], [ "AH", 0.940362811791, 0.980272108844 ], [ "D", 0.980272108844, 1.04013605442 ], [ "V", 1.04013605442, 1.10997732426 ], [ "EH", 1.10997732426, 1.21972789116 ], [ "N", 1.21972789116, 1.289569161 ], [ "CH", 1.289569161, 1.42925170068 ], [ "ER", 1.42925170068, 1.51904761905 ], [ "Z", 1.51904761905, 1.57891156463 ], [ "R", 1.57891156463, 1.66870748299 ], [ "AH", 1.66870748299, 1.69863945578 ], [ "K", 1.69863945578, 1.75850340136 ], [ "AO", 1.75850340136, 1.88820861678 ], [ "R", 1.88820861678, 1.91814058957 ], [ "D", 1.91814058957, 1.95804988662 ], [ "AH", 1.95804988662, 1.99795918367 ], [ "D", 1.99795918367, 2.07777777778 ], [ "AH", 2.07777777778, 2.10770975057 ], [ "N", 2.10770975057, 2.18752834467 ], [ "DH", 2.18752834467, 2.22743764172 ], [ "AH", 2.22743764172, 2.2873015873 ], [ "S", 2.2873015873, 2.42698412698 ], [ "B", 2.42698412698, 2.51678004535 ], [ "UH", 2.51678004535, 2.68639455782 ], [ "K", 2.68639455782, 2.79614512472 ], [ "sp", 2.79614512472, 2.81609977324 ], [ "R", 2.81609977324, 2.95578231293 ], [ "IY", 2.95578231293, 3.00566893424 ], [ "L", 3.00566893424, 3.09546485261 ], [ "IY", 3.09546485261, 3.23514739229 ], [ "AH", 3.23514739229, 3.27505668934 ], [ "K", 3.27505668934, 3.41473922902 ], [ "ER", 3.41473922902, 3.68412698413 ], [ "D", 3.68412698413, 3.75396825397 ], [ "sp", 3.75396825397, 4.01337868481 ] ] }


 /**
  * Set up D3JS
  */
 var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 401])
  .range([0, width]);
 var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 800])
  .range([height, 0]);

 /** Center the stream vertically **/
 var shift = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 0])
  .range([-height/2, 0]);

 /** Draw a stream segment **/
 var pathGenerator = d3.area()
  .curve( myCurveBundle.beta(0) )
  .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
  .y1(function(d) { return y(d + 72 ); }) /** 72 is just some arbitrary thickess given to the graph **/
  .y0(function(d) { return y(d); });

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);



 /**
  * Render the chart
  */
 
 /** Draw the stream, on a per-segment basis **/
 var path = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data.TextGrid.phone)
  .enter().append("path")
   .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + x(Math.floor(d[1]*100)) + ", " + shift(i) + ")"; })
   .attr("class", function(d) { return "segment " + d[0]; })
   .on('click', function(d, i) { playFromTo(Math.floor(d[1] * 1000), Math.floor(d[2] * 1000)); })
   .attr("d", function(d) { return pathGenerator(data.prosody.slice( Math.floor(d[1]*100), Math.floor(d[2]*100)+1)); });
```

```css
.segment { fill: #ccc; }
.segment.sp { display: none; }

/** Adapted from Margaret Horrigan for American English **/
.segment.IY { fill: #7AC141; }
.segment.IH { fill: #F9C5DC; }
.segment.UH { fill: #FF00FF; }
.segment.UW { fill: #0153A5; }
.segment.EY { fill: #8B8C90; }
.segment.EH { fill: #E61A25; }
.segment.AX { fill: #DF5435; }
.segment.ER { fill: #805EAA; }
.segment.AO { fill: #E2A856; }
.segment.OY { fill: #2E3094; }
.segment.OW { fill: #FC2B1C; }
.segment.AE { fill: #21201E; }
.segment.AH { fill: #DF5435; }
.segment.AA { fill: #bf181f; }
.segment.AY { fill: #FFFFFF; }
.segment.AW { fill: #7C4540; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@5.4.0/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

(The bundle code is adapted from [bundle.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/src/curve/bundle.js) in *d3-shape*.)

I'm *very* close: if you inspect the SVG, you'll see that, even though nothing is shown, paths actually do get created.

If you look at the first "visible" segment (class `segment M`) you'll see that it contains a *move* command somewhere in the middle:

```
M31.122194513715712,398.532825
```

If I rename it to a line command, like so:

```
L31.122194513715712,398.532825
```

…then that segment will show.

I'm confused as to which part of the custom curve is responsible for that. **How can I turn that M into an L?**

The resulting paths also happen to lack final Zs. How would I go about handling that?

I haven't found much help regarding custom curves in D3JS. Any help is welcome.

Comment: For your aide more than ours, can you also file this on the d3js issue tracker? They may have already gotten this question before with a known solution that someone who does not use stackoverflow, but does contribute to d3, might know.

Comment: I ending up posting a comment on this related thread: https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/70

Comment: Thanks for posting that comment-- I'm also curious about why it was excluded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Calling `areaStart` and `areaEnd`:

It looks like you've copied the `areaStart` and `areaEnd` functions from `d3.curveBasis` into your custom curve, which is mainly drawn from `d3.curveBundle`.

You can't just copy the code from `d3.curveBasis` into `d3.curveBundle` because `this` refers to different things. `this._basis` (your instance of d3.curveBasis) can not access `this._line` (the variable it expects for `areaStart` and `areaEnd`, and is accessible via your `customBundle`).

You could change `this._line` to `this._basis._line`, but if you notice, all the line functions in `d3.curveBundle` call their respective `this._basis` functions (e.g. `lineStart` calls `this._basis.lineStart()`). If you do the same here it should be equivalent:

```
areaStart: {
    // this._basis._line = 0; // this should work, for now
    this._basis.areaStart(); // but this makes more sense semantically
},
areaEnd: {
    // this._basis._line = NaN; // this should work, for now
    this._basis.areaEnd(); // but this makes more sense semantically
}
```

The added benefit of doing things this way is that if `d3.curveBasis` changes its implementation in the future, this has a higher chance of being compatible.

#### No need for `new`:

As a side note, in your constructor you create a new instance of `this._basis` using the `new` operator:

```
this._basis = new d3.curveBasis(context);
```

The `Basis` constructor via `new` is used internally in the d3 modules, but in the bundled library, it's a functional constructor. It can just be:

```
this._basis = d3.curveBasis(context);
```

Though using `new` doesn't seem to be breaking anything. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468106/6184972 for more information.

#### Should you be using curve bundles to render areas?

As you note, d3.curveBundle is "intended to work with d3.line, not d3.area." It should be worth asking whether you should be using `curveBundle` to render areas, since the omission seems deliberate. From https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/70, @mbostock writes:

> Correct, d3.curveBundle is only intended to work with d3.line. It’s
>   for hierarchical edge bundling, not for rendering areas.

See also https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveBundle.

You should probably compare to `curveBundle` with other interpolation methods to see whether using it distorts your area in a misleading manner.

#### Results:

All together, the changes can be seen in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g4ya2qso/

#### Alternatively:

Alternatively, since the functionality resembles `d3.curveBundle` so much, you can just add methods for `.areaStart` and `.areaEnd`, and omit all of the other custom code, like so:

```
var myCurveBundle = (function custom(beta) {
    function myCustomBundle(context) {
      var bundle = d3.curveBundle.beta(beta)(context);
      bundle.areaStart = function () {
        bundle._basis.areaStart();
      };
      bundle.areaEnd = function () {
        bundle._basis.areaEnd();
      };
      return bundle;
    }
    myCustomBundle.beta = function(newBeta) {
      return custom(+newBeta);
    };
    return myCustomBundle;
})(0.85);
```

```js
///////////////////// Custom curves.

/** Bundle-ish.
 * Trying to adapt curveBundle for use with areas…
 */
var myCurveBundle = (function custom(beta) {
  function myCustomBundle(context) {
    var bundle = d3.curveBundle.beta(beta)(context);
    bundle.areaStart = function () {
      bundle._basis.areaStart();
    };
    bundle.areaEnd = function () {
      bundle._basis.areaEnd();
    };
    return bundle;
  }
  myCustomBundle.beta = function(newBeta) {
    return custom(+newBeta);
  };
  return myCustomBundle;
})(0.85);

///////////////////// The chart.

 var width = 960;
 var height = 540;
 var data = [];
 data.prosody = [116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.473, 116.578, 125.552, 134.888, 144.225, 153.561, 162.898, 172.235, 181.571, 190.908, 200.244, 209.581, 218.917, 227.715, 218.849, 209.591, 200.333, 191.076, 181.818, 172.560, 163.302, 154.044, 144.787, 135.529, 126.271, 117.013, 107.755, 98.498, 89.240, 97.511, 118.857, 140.202, 161.547, 182.893, 192.100, 188.997, 185.895, 182.792, 179.690, 176.587, 173.485, 170.382, 167.280, 164.177, 161.075, 157.972, 154.870, 151.767, 148.665, 145.562, 142.460, 139.357, 136.255, 133.152, 130.050, 126.947, 124.244, 122.275, 120.307, 118.338, 116.369, 114.400, 112.431, 110.462, 108.493, 106.524, 104.555, 102.586, 100.617, 98.648, 99.659, 101.531, 103.402, 105.273, 107.145, 109.016, 110.887, 112.758, 114.630, 116.501, 118.372, 120.244, 122.115, 123.986, 125.857, 127.729, 129.600, 131.471, 133.343, 135.214, 137.085, 138.956, 140.828, 142.699, 144.570, 146.442, 148.313, 150.184, 149.175, 146.384, 143.594, 140.803, 138.013, 135.222, 132.432, 129.642, 126.851, 124.061, 121.270, 118.480, 115.689, 112.899, 110.109, 107.318, 104.528, 101.737, 98.947, 96.156, 93.366, 90.576, 87.785, 84.995, 82.204, 79.414, 76.623, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 76.601, 78.414, 80.227, 82.041, 83.854, 85.667, 87.480, 89.294, 91.107, 92.920, 94.733, 96.547, 98.360, 100.173, 101.986, 103.800, 105.613, 107.426, 109.239, 111.053, 112.866, 114.679, 116.492, 115.917, 114.338, 112.760, 111.181, 109.602, 108.023, 106.444, 104.865, 103.286, 101.707, 100.128, 98.549, 96.970, 95.391, 93.812, 92.233, 90.654, 89.075, 87.534, 88.055, 88.646, 89.237, 89.827, 90.418, 91.009, 91.600, 92.191, 92.782, 93.373, 93.964, 94.555, 95.146, 95.737, 96.328, 96.919, 97.509, 98.100, 98.691, 99.282, 99.873, 100.062, 98.230, 96.399, 94.567, 92.736, 90.904, 89.072, 87.241, 85.409, 83.578, 81.746, 79.914, 78.083, 78.839, 80.880, 82.922, 84.964, 87.006, 89.048, 91.090, 93.132, 95.174, 97.216, 99.257, 101.299, 103.341, 105.383, 107.425, 109.467, 111.509, 113.551, 112.633, 110.755, 108.877, 106.999, 105.121, 103.243, 101.365, 99.487, 97.609, 95.731, 93.853, 91.975, 90.097, 88.219, 86.341, 84.463, 82.585, 80.707, 78.829, 76.951, 78.067, 81.290, 84.513, 87.736, 90.958, 94.181, 97.404, 100.627, 103.849, 107.072, 110.295, 113.517, 116.740, 119.963, 123.186, 126.408, 129.631, 132.854, 136.077, 139.299, 142.522, 145.745, 148.968, 152.190, 155.413, 154.840, 152.899, 150.958, 149.017, 147.076, 145.135, 143.194, 141.253, 139.312, 137.371, 135.429, 133.488, 131.547, 129.606, 127.665, 125.724, 124.874, 126.734, 128.594, 130.454, 132.314, 134.174, 136.034, 137.894, 139.754, 141.614, 143.474, 145.334, 147.194, 149.054, 150.914, 152.774, 154.634, 156.494, 158.354, 160.214, 162.074, 163.934, 165.664, 161.795, 157.761, 153.726, 149.692, 145.658, 141.624, 137.589, 133.555, 129.521, 125.487, 121.452, 117.418, 113.384, 109.350, 105.316, 101.281, 97.247, 93.213, 89.179, 85.144, 81.110, 77.076, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];
 data.TextGrid = {  "phone" : [ /** segment type, beginning, and end of each segment **/ [ "sp", 0.0124716553288, 0.271882086168 ], [ "M", 0.271882086168, 0.401587301587 ], [ "OW", 0.401587301587, 0.521315192744 ], [ "S", 0.521315192744, 0.660997732426 ], [ "T", 0.660997732426, 0.710884353741 ], [ "AH", 0.710884353741, 0.760770975057 ], [ "V", 0.760770975057, 0.820634920635 ], [ "DH", 0.820634920635, 0.860544217687 ], [ "IY", 0.860544217687, 0.940362811791 ], [ "AH", 0.940362811791, 0.980272108844 ], [ "D", 0.980272108844, 1.04013605442 ], [ "V", 1.04013605442, 1.10997732426 ], [ "EH", 1.10997732426, 1.21972789116 ], [ "N", 1.21972789116, 1.289569161 ], [ "CH", 1.289569161, 1.42925170068 ], [ "ER", 1.42925170068, 1.51904761905 ], [ "Z", 1.51904761905, 1.57891156463 ], [ "R", 1.57891156463, 1.66870748299 ], [ "AH", 1.66870748299, 1.69863945578 ], [ "K", 1.69863945578, 1.75850340136 ], [ "AO", 1.75850340136, 1.88820861678 ], [ "R", 1.88820861678, 1.91814058957 ], [ "D", 1.91814058957, 1.95804988662 ], [ "AH", 1.95804988662, 1.99795918367 ], [ "D", 1.99795918367, 2.07777777778 ], [ "AH", 2.07777777778, 2.10770975057 ], [ "N", 2.10770975057, 2.18752834467 ], [ "DH", 2.18752834467, 2.22743764172 ], [ "AH", 2.22743764172, 2.2873015873 ], [ "S", 2.2873015873, 2.42698412698 ], [ "B", 2.42698412698, 2.51678004535 ], [ "UH", 2.51678004535, 2.68639455782 ], [ "K", 2.68639455782, 2.79614512472 ], [ "sp", 2.79614512472, 2.81609977324 ], [ "R", 2.81609977324, 2.95578231293 ], [ "IY", 2.95578231293, 3.00566893424 ], [ "L", 3.00566893424, 3.09546485261 ], [ "IY", 3.09546485261, 3.23514739229 ], [ "AH", 3.23514739229, 3.27505668934 ], [ "K", 3.27505668934, 3.41473922902 ], [ "ER", 3.41473922902, 3.68412698413 ], [ "D", 3.68412698413, 3.75396825397 ], [ "sp", 3.75396825397, 4.01337868481 ] ] }

 /**
  * Set up D3JS
  */
 var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 401])
  .range([0, width]);
 var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 800])
  .range([height, 0]);

 /** Center the stream vertically **/
 var shift = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 0])
  .range([-height/2, 0]);

 /** Draw a stream segment **/
 var pathGenerator = d3.area()
  .curve( myCurveBundle.beta(0) )
  .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
  .y1(function(d) { return y(d + 72 ); }) /** 72 is just some arbitrary thickess given to the graph **/
  .y0(function(d) { return y(d); });

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

 /**
  * Render the chart
  */
 
 /** Draw the stream, on a per-segment basis **/
 var path = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data.TextGrid.phone)
  .enter().append("path")
   .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + x(Math.floor(d[1]*100)) + ", " + shift(i) + ")"; })
   .attr("class", function(d) { return "segment " + d[0]; })
   .on('click', function(d, i) { playFromTo(Math.floor(d[1] * 1000), Math.floor(d[2] * 1000)); })
   .attr("d", function(d) { return pathGenerator(data.prosody.slice( Math.floor(d[1]*100), Math.floor(d[2]*100)+1)); });
```

```css
.segment { fill: #ccc; }
.segment.sp { display: none; }

/** Adapted from Margaret Horrigan for American English **/
.segment.IY { fill: #7AC141; }
.segment.IH { fill: #F9C5DC; }
.segment.UH { fill: #FF00FF; }
.segment.UW { fill: #0153A5; }
.segment.EY { fill: #8B8C90; }
.segment.EH { fill: #E61A25; }
.segment.AX { fill: #DF5435; }
.segment.ER { fill: #805EAA; }
.segment.AO { fill: #E2A856; }
.segment.OY { fill: #2E3094; }
.segment.OW { fill: #FC2B1C; }
.segment.AE { fill: #21201E; }
.segment.AH { fill: #DF5435; }
.segment.AA { fill: #bf181f; }
.segment.AY { fill: #FFFFFF; }
.segment.AW { fill: #7C4540; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@5.4.0/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was most helpful and clarified a few things; kudos for the shorter alternative.